# org.json.JSONException: Value at of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: android, json

I'm getting this error

```
org.json.JSONException: Value [{"value":"6","startDate":"1970-01-01T00:00:00","measureTypeId":1,"endDate":"1970-01-01T00:00:00","isTimeSet":true},{"value":"12","startDate":"1970-01-01T00:00:00","measureTypeId":1,"endDate":"1970-01-01T00:00:00","isTimeSet":true}] at measureTooteets of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

while executing the below code,

```
if (tweetType == TooteetType.MEASURE) {
            measureJson = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MEASURE_JSON));
            Log.d("ss","Measure json frm database______________"+measureJson);
            if (measureJson != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(measureJson);
                 //   JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("measureTooteets");
                 //   new JSONObject("{your string}")
                    String notes = object.getString("measureTooteets");
                    JSONArray jsonArray  = new JSONArray(notes);
                    mMeasure = new Measure(jsonArray);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

where Measure(jsonArray) will access the below code

```
public Measure(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        try {
//            JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("MeasureTooteets");
            for(int i =0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                id = jsonObject.optString("id");
                tooteetId = jsonObject.optString("tooteetId");
                laneId = jsonObject.optString("laneId");
                startDate = jsonObject.optString("startDate");
                endDate = jsonObject.optString("endDate");
                value = jsonObject.optDouble("value");
                measureTypeId = jsonObject.optInt("measureTypeId");
                isTimeSet = jsonObject.optBoolean("isTimeSet");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Please suggest me any idea to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Replace these two statements:

```
 String notes = object.getString("measureTooteets");
 JSONArray jsonArray  = new JSONArray(notes);
```

with that statement:

```
 JSONArray jsonArray  = object.getJSONArray("measureTooteets");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but the problem may be in the content of the **measureJson**, please, try to give me an example of the content that exists in this object to help me in detecting the problem.